# RxJava : Retrying a subscriber using retryWhen()

Tags: rx-java, vert.x

I am consuming a REST api using Vertx RxJava subscriber. I want to retry a request when there is a specific error, below is my code.
When I run this, the retry keeps happening infinitely, I'd rather have it retry just thrice.

I am new to RxJava and still getting the hang of doing things in Rx way.
Can someone tell if I am missing something? Thanks!

```
responseSingle.map(response -> {
            //do some stuff
            return responseBody;

        }).retryWhen(errors -> {
                    errors.flatMap(error -> {
                        log.info("==================== caught error ==================== ");
                        // For IOExceptions, we  retry
                        if (error instanceof MySpecificException) {
                            log.info("==================== retrying request ==================== ");
                            return Observable.just(null);
                        }

                        // For anything else, don't retry
                        return errors;
                    });
                    return errors;
                }
        ).onErrorReturn(t -> {
            //do some stuff
            return responseBody;
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `retryWhen`  and `retry` is good enough.

```
responseSingle.map(response -> {
        //do some stuff
        return responseBody;

    })
    .retry((attempts,error) -> attempts<3 && error instanceof MySpecificException)  
    .onErrorReturn(t -> {
        //do some stuff
        return responseBody;
    });
```

It will retry if expression inside retry returns `true`

Comment: You are welocme

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.retry(count)`, not tested but it should work.

```
responseSingle.map(response -> {
            //do some stuff
            return responseBody;

        })
                .retry(3) // count of retries
                .retryWhen(errors -> {
                    errors.flatMap(error -> {
                        log.info("==================== caught error ==================== ");
                        // For IOExceptions, we  retry
                        if (error instanceof MySpecificException) {
                            log.info("==================== retrying request ==================== ");
                            return Observable.just(null);
                        }

                        // For anything else, don't retry
                        return errors;
                    });
                    return errors;
                }
        ).onErrorReturn(t -> {
            //do some stuff
            return responseBody;
        });
```